# How to mock a class that is constantly changing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, dynamics-crm-2011, moq

I have a class [XrmServiceContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg695819(v=crm.5).aspx) and it changes each time the CRM configuration changes.

My service class accepts it in its constructor:

```
public class fooService(XrmServiceContext xrmServiceContext)
{
   //implementation
}
```

I need to mock XrmServiceContext in order to set up expectations and verify behavior for my unit tests.

**How do I mock this class in order to define behavior in my tests for fooService?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this by creating a fake `IOrganizationService` object used in the constructor for `XrmServiceContext`, I recommend using: https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy. You can learn more about how to use FakeXrmEasy, personally I found it very easy, by looking at https://dynamicsvalue.com/get-started/overview.

Here is brief overview of using the library for your purpose:

```
var context = new XrmFakedContext();

context.ProxyTypesAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Account));

//You'll need to setup this fake to have the data necessary to support your use cases for XrmServiceContext.

var account = new Account() { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), Name = "My First Faked Account yeah!" };

context.Initialize(new List<Entity>() {
                account
            });


var service = context.GetFakedOrganizationService();

using (var context = new XrmServiceContext(service))
{
    //Create instance of fooService class
    var testableFooService = new fooService(context);

    //TODO: Run your test.
}
```

Comment: Thx a mill for recommending FakeXrmEasy! Need to update the documentation page cause the proxy types assembly is automatically detected if you use early bound types in the Initialize method... making it even more simple to setup. It would be really needed whenever you aren't initalising anything, like, an empty initial state.

Comment: @Jordi Thanks for writing and sharing FakeXrmEasy, it's the single most valuable library to assist with developing for Dynamics CRM - I use it constantly and recommend it to all developers I work with!

Comment: @Jordi, will the FakeXrmEasy ever support connecting to CRM?  That's my final straw keeping me on XrmUnitTest.

Comment: Hey @Daryl, that's a good question. Personally, connecting to CRM is integration testing to me, and I could do that with a real CRM instance (i.e. without using fakes). I wouldn't mix the 2 in the one Nuget package, personally.  I.e. for unit testing, makes sense to run a plugin directly with .ExecutePlugin, but in a real CRM, that might be triggered indirectly via a .Create() or .Update() message.

Comment: So @Jordi, you would write completely different unit tests to support integration testing?  You would also require the code to be tested to be deployed?

Comment: @Daryl, I personally would write integration tests in a different project using might trigger after the unit test phase in a CI / Build process yep. They aren't unit tests, but integration tests in my opinion and they would need different methods probably. I.e. rather than .ExecuteCodeActivty (in unit tests) it would be .WaitForWorkflow("name id") in integration testing. So, unit tests as test driven development, and integration as kind of automated end 2 end testing yep. What do you think?

Comment: @Jordi, with some minimal upfront in my tests, I have them setup to run either against a faked IOrganizationService, or against a real IOrganizationService.  This means I get integration testing for the cost of defining a few Guids.

Comment: @Daryl, I've raised an [enhancement issue on Git](https://github.com/jordimontana82/fake-xrm-easy/issues/87) to get community feedback about this. Sorry for the delay...

Answer (score 1):

`XrmServiceContext` should be considered a 3rd party API.

Create an abstraction of the functionality you want from the service and wrap/adapt the context in the implementation.

```
public interface IXrmServiceContext {
    //api endpoints you want
}
```

So instead of passing around the concrete service context pass the abstractions to your services.

```
public class fooService {
    public fooService (IXrmServiceContext xrmServiceContext){

    }
   //implementation
}
```

This will make it a lot easier to set up expectations and verify behavior for your unit tests.